# How to connect MS Access database to Java Applet

Tags: java, database, ms-access, applet, bluej

We have to create a Java project on ATM Mechanism. We plan to connect it to a database also.
Could you please help me as to how I can connect an MS Access database to a Java applet which we have created using BlueJ?
Thank you.

Comment: Why are you using an applet? is this a requirement?

Comment: No. But it is easier using an applet. Could you please help regarding the database connectivity?

Answer (score 3):

Connecting the applet with MSAccess would be very complex, because of applet security limitations. An applet is not supposed to access local resources (files), so you would have to  add all kinds of signatures to the applet for the browser to allow this (I did something like this about 12 years ago, and from my knowledge, the applet security limitations are still in place, or even worse).

But if you do manage to access the local filesystem, you can use some library like [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) or access the `mdb` file directly using jdbc/odbc driver as [shown here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35018/Access-MS-Access-Databases-from-Java).